# $\sin (x) \ e^{-x}$ limit

Tags: calculus, limits

The problem I have is:

> $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \sin{(x)}\ e^{-x}$

Things I've tried:

1. Researching how to do this problem, I've come across kind of similar examples that use either Taylors Rule, L'Hopitals Rule, or the Squeeze Theorem. Not sure which one to use.
2. On Wolfram the anser is $0$.
3. Broke the problem apart into $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \sin{(x)}\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} e^{-x}$

$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \sin{(x)}=[-1,1]$

$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} e^{-x}=0$

Comment: $$|\sin x|\le1$$ for real $x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|(\sin x)e^{-x}|\leq e^{-x}\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: So since $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \sin{(x)}=[-1,1]$ and $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} e^{-x}=0$ then $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \sin{(x)}\ e^{-x}=0$?

Comment: $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\sin x=[-1,1]$ is not a valid expression. A limit value must be a number, not an interval.

Comment: The fact is, $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\sin x$ does not exist.

Comment: Okay I see. When I put in $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \sin{(x)}$ on Wolfram it said "$-1$ to $1$". So was unsure how to write that. In this case though, a limit that does not exist times zero is zero?

Comment: The trick here is the so called Squeeze Theorem. Although $\sin x$ has no limit as $x\rightarrow\infty$, that does not matter. Because $0\leq|(\sin x)e^{-x}|\leq e^{-x}$ and left, right side both tend to zero as $x\rightarrow\infty$. The constant function $0$ has limit the same $0$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Think about it this (non-rigorous) way: No matter what value $x$ takes, $-1 \leq sin(x) \leq 1$.  $e^{-x}$, however, approaches 0 as $x$ approaches $\infty$.  As such, the product of a term tending to 0 and a small finite number ([-1, 1]) tends to 0.

Comment: What it meant probably is that, $\sin x$ assumes every value in $[-1,1]$ as accumulation point as $x\rightarrow\infty$. In other words, given any number $c$ in $[-1,1]$, there is a sequence $a_{n}\rightarrow\infty$ such that $\sin a_{n}\rightarrow c$.

Answer (score 1):

For fun:

Let $x \gt 0:$

$0\le |\dfrac{\sin x}{e^x}| \le \dfrac{1}{e^x}\lt\dfrac{1}{x}.$

Used: $e^x = 1+x+x^2/2! +...\gt x.$

Let $\epsilon >0$ be given.

Choose $M$, real, such that $M >1/\epsilon.$

For $x\gt M$ we have:

$0\le |\dfrac{\sin x}{e^x}| \lt \dfrac{1}{x} \lt\dfrac{1}{M} \lt \epsilon.$